# Fetch refuses to make a request

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a cross-site GET request to REST API on another server, but I always get `TypeError: Network request failed`.

I have tried everything I could think of:

- the same request works on localhost, but fails when I replace IP with remote one
- using `curl` with the same remote URL address works
- `tcpdump` shows that no request is even attempted - nothing gets sent to remote server (and I double checked that tcpdump works)
- there is no request in `Network` tab and no additional error/warning message in `Console` tab of developer tools.

Checking [fetch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) doesn't show anything that could cause such failure. Any ideas?

Comment: Presumably you can perform a GET to some established site. So check server is running & firewall is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Argh - I found the answer the minute I have posted the question. It's `uMatrix` plugin which does what it's expected to - blocks unwanted network requests.

I'll leave the question here if someone else in the future encounters a similar problem.